# Jquery UI Dialog - returning value of loaded aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using the Jquery UI Dialog widget as well as the load command to open an existing aspx page within a dialog box

my code loads up the aspx page just fine.

```
$('#divCancelInspection').load('WOCancel.aspx').dialog({ /*properties specified*/ });
```

In my WOCancel.aspx page I have two buttons where I would want to return a value back to my calling page.

In my WOCancel.aspx

```
 $(document).ready(function() {      
   $('#btnCancelInspection').click(function() { /* return a value */ }); 
});
```

So now where I am stumped is how do I return the value back to my main page that created the dialog.

---

Now on a side note I know that a property set in my dialog box can be to specify the buttons.  But I was wondering if there was a different way like I specified above?  Otherwise I'll use something like below...

```
dialog({
 buttons: {
  'save': function() {/* code to find control value within dialog and use it*/ }, 
  Cancel: function () { /* close the dialog window */}
 }
});
```

Comment: You are using jquery ui dialog, it is on the same page that you opened the dialog just that the div pops out.

Comment: So I really shouldn't be using the ui dialog to load the external page in this scenario?  I am better off just creating the WOCancel.aspx page in a div tag in my main page?

Comment: does the aspx page contain html, head etc or a part of html?

Comment: the plan was to contain its own html head, etc.  But it is not necessarily set in stone

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using the second method

Now on a side note I know that a property set in my dialog box can be to specify the buttons. But I was wondering if there was a different way like I specified above? Otherwise I'll use something like below...

```
dialog({
 buttons: {
  'save': function() {/* code to find control value within dialog and use it*/ }, 
  Cancel: function () { /* close the dialog window */}
 }
});
```